# Detecting different operating systems and platforms

Tags: c#, mono, operating-system, cross-platform, platform

I am working on a Cross-Platform open-source project. My application is going to support Android, iOS, MAC OS X, Windows and Linux.

The first idea is to use the following code:

```
Environment.OSVersion.Platform
```

But it is not enough since I cannot cover iOS and Android. I think it is better to check the OS base and version to decide on the OS type. e.g.  iOS is a UNIX-based operating system. so I can check the Version or some other properties to make sure it is iOS.

Since I do not have access to Android or iOS and my search was not successful, I need your help to get these versions for each OS.

Sincerely yours,
Peyman Mortazavi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
public static bool IsAndroid {
   get {
      return (Type.GetType("Android.Runtime") != null);
   }
}
```

And perhaps:

```
public static bool IsIphoneOS {
   get {
      return (Type.GetType("MonoTouch.Constants") != null);
   }
}
```

Those will I suppose only work on MonoTouch or Mono for Android, but you could use the same approach. Either that or rely on correct #define values for your build platform.

Answer (score -1):

I'd love a cross platform function that did this for me.  Currently I have to create a function with ifdefs in and call the specific platform API calls in each.

```
#ifdef Q_WS_MACX
 return "MAC";
#else
 return "LINUX";
#endif
```

Obviously I do this in C++ Qt